# slideToggle() (jQuery) is not woking in IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have simple call to slideToggle like below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Btn_WebCategories").click(function(){
   $("q").slideToggle("slow");  //  slide
  });

//
// Second part: below not working. 
//
  $("#ExclBlockBtn").click(function(){
  $("ExWeb").slideToggle("slow");
  });
```

In IE6 slideToggle on "q" element is working fine, but in the second part ("ExWeb" element) which is much similar to first one is not working. Also above code is working fine in FF4.0.

I have tried by giving speed parameter differently.

Thanks in advance.

})

Comment: Please add your HTML code here or post it to http://jsfiedle.net. Every individual situation needs often an individual solution.

Comment: @reporter There is no site name http://jsfiedle.net/

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself if you *really* need it to work in IE6. Consider:

http://www.theie6countdown.com/default.aspx

If anything, the stats published by Microsoft reveal that, for all intents and purposes, IE6 is not used except on in developing countries (pirated copies of WinXP?), and on corporate networks that need it for their intranets.

Comment: Companies still use IE6 internally for business applications, some can't upgrade.

Comment: Yeah... Those are probably going to be around for a long while. I tend to ignore them, though -- IT departments tend to install FF in addition to IE6 when it's the case, so that users can securely browse non-corporate sites.

Comment: yeah, some people in some place is still using ie6 because they don't want to be bothered install another browser. just install the old version of windows (like win xp) and browsing

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the # in your selector: #q and #ExWeb

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Btn_WebCategories").click(function(){
   $("#q").slideToggle("slow");  //  slide
  });

//
// Second part: below not working. 
//
  $("#ExclBlockBtn").click(function(){
  $("#ExWeb").slideToggle("slow");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

IE6 doesn't know `<ExWeb/>` , it's not a valid HTML-tagName(assuming you're working on an (X)HTML-document). 
 `<q/>` is a valid tagName.